# Passing data from Kafka Consumer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I wanna get data from Kafka, this method success get record but can't pass to a variable. This is my code

```
public void subscribeFromKafka() throws Exception {

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KAFKA_SERVERS);
    props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test");
    props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
    props.setProperty("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
    props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    
    try (KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props)) {
        System.out.println("Receiving from Kafka . . .");
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(KAFKA_TOPIC_URL));
        // Set a timeout for the loop, or you can use another mechanism to break out of the loop.
        long endTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + TIMEOUT_MILLIS;
    
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTimeMillis) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                System.out.println("Received data: " + record.value());
                result.add(record.value());
            }
        }

        System.out.println(result + " this is the result from Kafka.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to subscribe from Kafka", e);
    }

}
```

How to solve it?

I tried add record from kafka consumer to arraylist of string, but record can't add to the arraylist

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is correctly subscribing to a Kafka topic, receiving records, and adding the values to the **result** list. If you are encountering issues with the result not being accessible outside the **try** block, it might be due to the scoping of the **result** variable.

In your code, you have declared the **result** list within the **subscribeFromKafka** method. This means that the **result** list is only accessible within the scope of that method. If you want to use the **result** list outside of the method, you should declare it as a class-level or instance variable.